# add days to datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to reproduce the same thing than this http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/ (the only problem is the format of the arrival field)
Field 1 : date of departure
Field 2: number of night
field 3: date of arrival
In this jsfiddle, is there any mean to have in field 3 the same format than field1 ? (i've made a test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranell/UgkgY/5/), but it didn't works )
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$.datepicker.formatDate` utility function: http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/244/

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate